# How do I know that a group generator really is from that group?

Tags: group-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras

I've asked the question [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/93171/different-definition-of-sl2-r-algebra) but I'm actually not that satisfied with an answer.

I have 3 generators that are (at least from what I read in every article I find) generators of $SL(2,\mathbb{R})$ group. But how do I know that they (the $\tilde{J}_i$ ones) are indeed generators of $SL(2,\mathbb{R})$?

Sure one can regard it as a change of basis (although I couldn't check the $M T_i M^{-1}=\tilde{T}_i$ rule with a given matrices, not even sure that's possible, since on one side I have $2\times 2$ matrix, and on the other a $4\times 1$ matrix (vector)).

But in general. How do I know that certain generator is indeed a generator of some specific group. Because, if it satisfies the rules of Lie algebra, that just means it forms a Lie algebra, not what that algebra is.

Comment: Firstly, you want to talk about generating sets, because every element is a generator. For example, $\mathbb{Z}=\langle 0, 1\rangle=\langle 1\rangle$. Anyway, the standard answer to your question is to prove that a known generating set is contained in the subgroup generated by your proposed generating set. For example, $1\in\langle 23, 7\rangle$ as $23$ and $7$ are coprime. Thus, $\langle 23, 7\rangle=\mathbb{Z}$. I think you have some underlying mis-understandings with the answer you got from Physics.SE. I will leave someone else to help you there though...

Comment: But those do not generate $SL(2,\mathbb{R})$ as a group. They are not even close in fact, as the group is uncountable, and there are only a finite number of those elements given.

Comment: You are both talking about generators as in the sense of elementary group theory where you generate groups from elements in that group. dingo_d is clearly talking about Lie-generators (evident from the tags) which are not in the group itself but in the corresponding Lie algebra and which generate it (a component at least) though the exponential map. An infinite Lie group of finite Lie-dimension is easily generated by a finite set of generators.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft The referenced question seems to deal with Lie algebra generators (which helps skip the uncountability gap)

Answer (score 1):

Okay. It took me a while to reorder all my terms to make it the more obvious but here I show that the two algebras have the same Lie-structure

Your Lie algebras is at heart a Vector space and  the $X,Y,Z$ matrices for a basis for the vector space. We know that we can just go ahead and form a new basis for the vector space by means of linear combinations of this basis and the one I am suggesting we transfer to is
$$J_0 = Y - Z, \qquad J_1 = X, \qquad J_2 = Y + Z$$
It's still the same Lie algebra since we let the Lie-bracket be as before and we find the brackets of these basis matrices to be

$$[J_0, J_1] = [Y - Z, X] = -2Z - 2Y = -2J_2$$

$$[J_0, J_2] = [Y - Z, Y + Z] = 2X = 2J_1$$

$$[J_1, J_2] = [X, Y  + Z] = 2Y - 2Z = 2J_0$$
From which we easily compare with the $\tilde{J}_i$-brackets and find that the structure is precisely the same. The linear map $f$ which maps matrices to differential operators according to
$$f : J_i \to \tilde{J_i}$$
could be used to form a Lie-algebra-homomorphism between these forms of $\mathfrak{sl}(2)$ so we find that they are indeed the same algebra.

(This is the first proof I have performed of this type and I am still quite new to this field so please check it for errors)

Comment: This sounds alright to me. I'll say this to my mentor and see if he agrees with it :)